# postMessage has different behavior in browsers

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, postmessage

I have the following files:

**a.html**

```
<p id="p1">a.html</p>
<iframe src="b.html"></iframe> <!-- we have a realm here -->
<script>
  frames[0].postMessage("some data", "*");
</script>
```

**b.html**

```
<p id="p1">b.html</p>
<script>
  window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
    console.log("event:", event);
  });
</script>
```

In the google chrome I don't see `console.log` message from `b.html` (I know what I should switch console tab for that), in the same moment in the firefox I see message. What's the matter?

Comment: Loading an iframe is asynchronous. The document you are sending a message to is `about:blank`. Wait for the iframe's `onload` event before posting your message.

Comment: @Kaiido yeah I did that as you adviced. But why in firefox it works well but not in chrome (without onload / setTimeout)?

Comment: Probably because they cached the document and were able to load it in parallel before your JS executed. It happens sometimes to me too, like once every ten tries. Just use `onload` and disregard this race-condition non-issue.

Comment: @Kaiido my question is reason to sort out with [incumbent settings object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#incumbent_settings_object_tracking) in promises. Do you know something about it? I also did [issue on github](https://github.com/mdn/sprints/issues/4027) where describe why section with incumbent is bad. If you know some answers I would be glad to see them on [github page issue](https://github.com/mdn/sprints/issues/4027)

Comment: What has this to do with incumbent settings objects? Here your issue is that the iframe will have two documents loaded; the initial `about:blank` one and the one loaded from the external document. If you wish to access the latter, you need to wait for it to load. And regarding the incumbent settings object, bzbarsky is well better versed into this than myself and I thought their explanation on the HTML issues were enough for you, I don't see how I can do it better than them.

Comment: @Kaiido why do you think that I have 2 iframe documents? `a.html` is start page, `b.html` is iframe page. I don't understand why you are mention `about:blank`.

Comment: @Kaiido Just there is interesting [incumbent settings object tracking conception](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#incumbent_settings_object_tracking) on the mdn. I wanted to check it, unfortunately basic and advanced examples are not explained why the are different. I mean why `<iframe></iframe>` is tracked but not tracked `<iframe src="a.html"></iframe>` if browser hasn't incumbent setting object tracking for promises hooks.